# Dart Asynchronous Execution

Tags: dart, dart-async

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void printDailyNewsDigest() {
  File file = new File("dailyNewsDigest.txt");
  Future future = file.readAsString();
  future.then((content) {
    print(content);
  });
}

void main() {
  printDailyNewsDigest();
  printWinningLotteryNumbers();//does something synchronous
  printWeatherForecast();//does something synchronous
  printBaseballScore();//does something synchronous
}
```

I have a simple question about asynchronous operations in Dart and 
specifically asynchronous operations in the above code. When does 
asynchronous execution begin in the above code? Does asynchronous 
execution begin with the file.readAsString() call or does it begin 
when main exits and the task queue is processed? The documentation 
that I read is a little vague about this one point.

If I had to guess, I would guess asynchronous execution would begin with
the call to file.readAsString(). Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It begins when `main()` the 'current thread of synchronous execution' is finished.
A part of `readAsString` is executed synchrounously but because it returns a Future it is obvious that somewhere inside `readAsString` some async operation was invoked. This means that it is scheduled for later execution.
When `main` is finished the event queue is processed and the next scheduled async operation is executed.